# i want to repeat a program many times. how do i record these results in another class

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Random;
public class test{
public static void main(String[] args){

    System.out.println(qq(30));
}

public static int qq(int range){ 
    Random generator=new Random();
    int[] aa = new int[range];     //create an array with "range" elements
    for (int w=0;w <range;w++) {
        aa[w] = generator.nextInt(20);// assign random numbers to array aa
    }
    int ee=0; //number of times 
    outerloop:
    for(int i =0;i<range;i++){
        for(int j=i+1;j<range-1;j++){
            if (aa[i]==aa[j] ){
                break outerloop;//if aa[i] and aa[j] are the same,break and return ee

            }
            else{
                ee++; //if aa[i] and aa[j] are not the same, ee++ and keep going 
            }
        }
    }
    return ee;//return the min number of failed match attempts

}
}
```

i want to repeat this program 10 times(receive 10 "ee"s),how do i create another class to save these results, so that i can use these 10 numbers to find an average later.

Comment: You can't record what a class does (practically speaking).  You could write the results out to a file, that's pretty normal.

Comment: OTOH, where you call `qq()` in `main`, you could put that in a loop, and record the results in an array.

Comment: you are right !thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the results in List or in Array. You don't have to create another class, you can use inbuilt utility classes or array to accomplish your goal.
To store values in List, replace your main method's body as follows.

```
java.util.List<Integer> l=new java.util.ArrayList<>();
int sum=0;
for (int i=0; i<10; i++){
    int a=qq(30);
    l.add(a);
    sum+=a;
}
System.out.print(sum);
```

If you want to use array of integer replace body of main method with following.

```
int ar[]=new int[10];
int sum=0;
for (int i=0; i<ar.length; i++){
    int a=qq(30);
    ar[i]=a;
    sum+=a;
}
System.out.print(sum);
```

If you don't want to store the results & just interested in sum than you don't have to use `ArrayList`.
You can try this one.

```
int sum=0;
for (int i=0; i<ar.length; i++)
    sum+=qq(30);
System.out.print(sum);
```